# How to check if an adapter was set on recyclerview?

Tags: android-recyclerview

binding.setAdapter(myRVAdapter);

Which sets the adapter for recycler view. Know it was already attached I wanna check if the recycler view has an existing adapter that was set not set again myRVAdapter twice because it reset the child items view. Was there a method the return if an adapter was set or null?

Comment: See [getAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView#getAdapter()).

Comment: Ah silly me, I keep getting the `Cannot resolve symbol 'getAdapter` but when I check if I selected the right recycler view binding. I was checking binding have recyclerviewlbl id. Thank you, it was my fault.